# Regex: Highlight an input in any case in TextView

Tags: java, android, regex, string, textview

I am implementing a search function on an app with the search results having the search keyword highlighted.

[image]

I have implemented this so far and it partially works:

```
public static String searchHighlightedKeyword(String keyword, String whole) {
    String highlighted = "<font color='#1e499f'><b>" + keyword +"</b></font>";
    return whole.replaceAll(keyword, highlighted);
}
```

However, it doesn't work when the cases don't match:
[image]

I figured I have to implement some sort of RegEx to achieve this but I don't have an idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case insensitive modifier to match the keyword (which you can also `Pattern.quote` to make matching safer as it escaped special regex metacharacters) and a `$0` backreference to the whole match:

```
public static String searchHighlightedKeyword(String keyword, String whole) {
    String highlighted = "<font color='#1e499f'><b>$0</b></font>";
    return whole.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(keyword), highlighted);
}
```

Here,

- `"(?i)"` - an inline case insensitive modifier
- `Pattern.quote(keyword)`  - a `keyword` with all special regex metacharacters escaped (so as `(` or `)` could not throw an exception)
- `$0` - in the replacement string, references the whole match value.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public void searchHighlightedKeyword(TextView textView, String keyword, String whole) {
        int startPos = whole.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase());
        if (startPos < 0) {
            textView.setText(whole);
            return;
        }
        int endPos = startPos + keyword.length();
        SpannableString spannable2 = new SpannableString(whole);
        spannable2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), startPos, endPos,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannable2);
    }
```